# CodeIgniter DataMapper with Nested Sets

Tags: codeigniter, nested-sets, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm trying to get a basic example of CodeIgniter DataMapper Nested Sets working using the included Nested Sets extension to DataMapper.  I have a table set up with a single tree in it:

```
+------+--------------+---------+----------+
| id   | name         | left_id | right_id |
+------+--------------+---------+----------+
| 2063 | Categories   |       1 |       74 |
| 2064 | Category 14  |      72 |       73 |
| 2065 | Category 18  |      64 |       71 |
| 2066 | Category 21  |      62 |       63 |
| 2067 | Category 22  |      60 |       61 |
| 2068 | Category 23  |      58 |       59 |
| 2069 | Category 24  |      56 |       57 |
| 2070 | Category 25  |      54 |       55 |
| 2071 | Category 58  |      52 |       53 |
| 2072 | Category 59  |      50 |       51 |
| 2073 | Category 62  |      48 |       49 |
| 2074 | Category 63  |      46 |       47 |
| 2075 | Category 75  |      44 |       45 |
| 2076 | Category 181 |      42 |       43 |
| 2077 | Category 182 |      40 |       41 |
| 2078 | Category 183 |      38 |       39 |
| 2079 | Category 184 |      36 |       37 |
| 2080 | Category 185 |      34 |       35 |
| 2081 | Category 186 |      32 |       33 |
| 2082 | Category 187 |      30 |       31 |
| 2083 | Category 188 |      28 |       29 |
| 2084 | Category 189 |      26 |       27 |
| 2085 | Category 190 |      24 |       25 |
| 2086 | Category 191 |      22 |       23 |
| 2087 | Category 192 |      20 |       21 |
| 2088 | Category 193 |      18 |       19 |
| 2089 | Category 194 |      16 |       17 |
| 2090 | Category 195 |      14 |       15 |
| 2091 | Category 196 |      12 |       13 |
| 2092 | Category 198 |      10 |       11 |
| 2093 | Category 199 |       8 |        9 |
| 2094 | Category 200 |       6 |        7 |
| 2095 | Category 201 |       4 |        5 |
| 2096 | Category 204 |       2 |        3 |
| 2097 | Category 125 |      69 |       70 |
| 2098 | Category 126 |      67 |       68 |
| 2099 | Category 127 |      65 |       66 |
+------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

I'm simply trying to dump the tree using the `dump_tree()` method from the documentation, but  I'm not getting any output at all.  Here's the code:

```
$tree = new Category();
$tree->get_root();
print_r($tree->dump_tree(array('name'), 'html', FALSE));
```

I know that the model is "working" because if I `print_r($tree)` before trying to use `dump_tree`, I see that the $tree object does contain my root node.  However, when I try to dump the entire tree, there is no output.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Thank you!

Oh, and here's a link to the documentation I'm referring to:  http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/extensions/nestedsets.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to include a "root_id" field even though there is only a single tree in the table.  According to the documentation this shouldn't be the case. I included a root_id field in my table and gave it a value of 1 for every entry.  The full tree now prints correctly.